# Android AsyncHttpClient, unable to find symbol class Header

Tags: android, networking, android-studio, header, asynchttpclient

I'm trying to create asynchronous rest call in [Android using a library `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient`](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) however, i'm unable to implement AsyncHttpResponseHandler's overridden methods because Android Studio cannot find an appropriate import for `Header` class

**How can I resolve the issue with the Header class not recognized by the Android Studio IDE?**

```
 public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
            }
```

I see that if I mouse over and click on the Header, I get the following message, but I don't know how to select one of the multiple choices in this menu (moving the mouse dismisses it)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the time I typed this question, I found the answer, hopefully it will help you:

Press Option + enter on Mac when this popup is visible, then **select `import org.apache.http.Header;` from the dropdown menu:**

[image]

Comment: I cant find this class anymore..,Has it been removed ?

Comment: Header does not exist in org.apache.http anymore as it has been deprecated, see the answer below

Comment: if you are using v23.0.1 then @monotheist answer is the correct one

Comment: Thank you !
Need add lib:  httpclient-4.4.1.2.jar  to project after import : import org.apache.http.Header;
Download lib here : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/cz/msebera/android/httpclient/4.4.1.2/

Answer (score 15):

The answer by Alex is no longer valid as org.Apache.http is deprecated from API level 22.

Please replace all references of org.apache.http to cz.msebera.android.httpclient
and use version 1.4.9 of loopj which includes the library.

For those who use gradle change your dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

Rebuild and then import cz.msebera.android.httpclient to use Header.

Comment: How do you use the cz.msemera.android.httpclient.header ?

Comment: If you are using Android studio, add the above command to build.gradle and recompile, then it will pull all the required libraries, then u can include it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the ambiguity in my question, I meant how do you prepare the Header as I was unable to find the documentation for cz.msemera.anroid.httpclient.header

Comment: can you clarify what do you mean by "prepare"?

Comment: By prepare I meant how do you add headers to the header object. I ended up adding the header to the AsyncClient it self using the .addHeader() method.

Comment: @monotheist I've added this dependency **compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'** to gradle. When I'm trying to Rebuild the project, I'm getting the error **Could not resolve com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9**

Comment: I use jcenter() as my repository, what about yours?

Comment: This answer worked for me. It took a couple of tries for Android Studio to see the header from 'import cz.msebera.android.httpclient'.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use gradle change your dependencies in build.gradle

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2'
    }`

In Ubuntu use ALT+Enter on the Header[] as explained above for the Mac

Which also changed the import I guessed at android.* to httpclient.header

```
import cz.msebera.android.*;                 
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
```